# Performance of the RegExp object

Tags: regex, typescript, class-validator

In the following code, the

I'd like to improve the performance by putting the RegExp object somewhere, but I can't figure out how to do the nest.

```
@ValidatorConstraint()
export class RegExp implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  validate(kana: string, args: ValidationArguments) {
    const str = new RegExp(/^[ァ-ヶー]+$/)
    return str.test(kana)
  }

  defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
    return 'Text should be'
  }
}
```

thanks

Comment: I don't know any typescript, but it looks like if regexp matching is a performance bottleneck with that code, it would be improved by creating the regexp object one time in a static or class context instead of within the method every time it's called. That said, for performance issues you always want to profile it first because often the slow part is not what you might think.

Comment: Thanks.
The code that displays it is now correct.
Does static context mean using COSNT in this way?

Comment: No static is not the same as const; search for "static members in typescript" to get more information. Also, please don't modify your question reflecting your solution, because that will void all previous comments about it. If you have found a solution yourself, just post (and accept) it as an answer.

Comment: sorry、I'm sorry,
I put it back in the form of a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need regexp only - simply use a built-in `Matches` validator:

```js
@Matches(/^[ァ-ヶー]+$/)
public field: string;
```

In this case it will reuse regexp on every validation.

Comment: Thanks!!
I didn't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of it this way.

```
const regexp = new RegExp(/^[ァ-ヶー]+$/)

@ValidatorConstraint()
export class RegExp implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  validate(kana: string, args: ValidationArguments) {
    return regexp.test(kana)
  }

  defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
    return 'Text should be'
  }
}
```

Comment: you should use `regexp` in the `validate` method and remove `str`.

Comment: Tanks, is this preventing me from creating a RegExp object every time?